# Potential Subject Verb Agreement error - in an English Textbook

Tags: grammar, verbs, aspect

"In what ways do the past affect the present?"

I read the above in an English textbook.  So that the verb agrees with "the past", should we have used "affects" instead of "affect"?

Comment: That's funny.  Do tell us the author.

Comment: No, it should read "In what ways does the past affect the present?".  It is possible--grammatical--to phrase the sentence "The past affects the present in what ways?", but I don't recommend it

Comment: 'In what ways do you see the past affecting the present ?'

Answer (score 1):

"In what ways do the past affect the present?"

You're right that the sentence as written has a subject-verb agreement error. Your proposed correction is wrong: *affect* here is a "plain form" or "bare infinitive", and so does not inflect for number. Number inflection must instead go on the auxiliary *do.*

As tautophile said in a comment, the correct rephrasing is "In what ways do**es** the past affect the present?"

---

Errors of "proximity agreement" like this are not incredibly uncommon, but they are definitely grammatical errors and are generally considered unacceptable in formal written prose, except for maybe in certain specific constructions where a combination of factors may lead to the grammatical sentence sounding weird, or the ungrammatical sentence sounding unusually acceptable. (I can't think of any guidelines about this, but maybe see [“What questions [is/are] your data team hoping to answer?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80218/what-questions-is-are-your-data-team-hoping-to-answer), [“What tools is everybody using?” or “What tools are everybody using?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192414), and [Is “What courses is everyone taking?” grammatical?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397573)  as examples of the kinds of sentences where native speakers may feel uncertain even after they have taken a moment to examine the sentence.)

Answer (score 0):

***Affect*** here is fine. However, the sentence is still ungrammatical.

First (and this is related, although it may not seem so until later), consider the pairing of ***ways do*** with ***the past***.

You want to use **do** with a plural subject and **does** with a singular subject.

As such, your sentence could be rephrased in two ways:

> In what **ways do the past** ***events*** affect the present?
>   In what **ways does the past** affect the present?

But, to further address your question, consider this:

> Does the past **affect** the future?
>   Yes, the past **affects** the future.

This at least *appears* to go against rules of subject-verb agreement—and you could think that one of these sentences is ungrammatical. However, that's not actually the case.

The reason for this is that the first sentence is a *question* and the second sentence is a *statement*.

[In questions](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_v&page=9UFx9rVePVV8.html), the order of subject and verb is reversed, and at least "part of" the verb comes before the subject:

> **Does** the past **affect** the future?

Here, **does** is a "helping verb," while **affect** is "the rest of" the verb.

(In other words, it's a verb + subject + verb construction.)

In the case of questions with helping verbs, subject-verb agreement is concerned with the helping verbs.

So, the agreement in this question is between the singular subject **the past** and the singular verb **does**.

A simpler form of subject-verb inversion in questions is when the verb *isn't* "split" by the subject:

> **Was** this answer helpful?

In short, your sentence *does* exhibit an error in subject-verb agreement. However, the error is with the verb **do**, not **affect**.

Comment: Jason Bassford - that was a wonderful answer!  Based on your input, I might suggest to the author (Derek Wee) that the question might be rephrased as "Does the past affect the present - and if yes, in what ways?"

Comment: @sumelic Thank you for pointing that out—I've edited my answer. Somehow, I hadn't even been aware of the fact that I'd made that unnecessary change.